# fazer a concatenação em parâmetros do $.keyframe.define

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
      $.keyframe.define([{
          name: 'tocaSlide',
          tMin : {'margin-left': tempoImagens},
          tMax : {'margin-left': tempoImagens},
      }]);
```

Mas preciso inserir '%' após as variáveis, da forma abaixo:

```
      $.keyframe.define([{
          name: 'tocaSlide',
          tMin'%' : { margin-left:-tempoImagens'%'},
          tMax'%' : { margin-left:-tempoImagens'%'}
      }]);
```

Da forma como fiz, está dando erro.
Qual a forma correta de fazer a concatenação em parâmetros do `$.keyframe.define`?

Também já tentei assim, mas dá erro do lado direito do dois pontos:

```
      $.keyframe.define([{
          name: 'tocaSlide',
          tMin + '%' + : { margin-left:-tempoImagens + '%' + },
          tMax + '%' + : { margin-left:-tempoImagens + '%' + }
      }]);
```

Eu até consegui da forma abaixo:

'%' : { "margin-left":-tempoImagens + "%"},
 '%' : { "margin-left":-tempoImagens + "%"},

Mas quando adicino a variável tMin e tMax do lado esquerdo da erro:

```
 tMin + "%" : { "margin-left":-tempoImagens + "%"},
 tMax + "%" : { "margin-left":-tempoImagens + "%"},
```

Comment: Ve se não da pra fazer só assim: tMin+'%' , no javascrip/jQuery usa o + pra concatenar

Comment: esse que é o problema, já tente assim também mas não funciona:

Comment: E assim ja tentou: 'tMin%': { 'margin-left:-tempoImagens%'}, ? peguei esse exemplo da docs

Comment: Não dá pois tMin é uma variável

Comment: Então tMin vem de um valor certo ? se for isso você tem que acrescentar % ja onde monta a variavel

Comment: Não, tMin e tMax recebem valores diferentes a cada iteração de um laço for;

Comment: Ja tentou concatenar dentro do laço ?

Comment: Aim, mas como faço para imprimir o resultado de uma variável de texto que contem todas a string dentro da função       $.keyframe.define([{ ???

Comment: Antes de entrar no $.keyframe faz um alias, var tMinConcat = tMin+'%'; e dentro de da função coloca  tMinConcat, acho que assim vais conseguir

Comment: Ta meio confuso para mim, Você poderia postar uma resposta com essa solução fazendo favor?

Comment: É que eu não tenmho certeza se vai dar certo, mas vou responder ali

Comment: vamos tentar, a esperança é a ultima que morre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que você tem os valores de `tMin` e `tMax` definidos, e queira concatenar, deve concatenar fora da array:

```
var tMinConcat = tMin + '%';
var tMaxConcat = tMax + '%';
var tMinAttr = 'margin-left:-tempoImagens' + '%';
var tMaxAttr = 'margin-left:-tempoImagens' + '%';
$.keyframe.define([{
  name: 'tocaSlide',
  tMinConcat: {tMinAttr},
  tMaxConcat: {tMaxAttr}
}]);
```

Veja que na verdade, é apenas a construção de um array javascript.

```
[{
  name: 'tocaSlide',
  tMinConcat: {tMinAttr},
  tMaxConcat: {tMaxAttr}
}]
```